# Devise and password_confirmation validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, testing, devise

I'm having trouble with devise and password confirmation.
I've created a model test in rails4 which looks like this:

```rb
test "user requires a password_confirmation" do
  user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
  assert user.valid?, "FactoryGirl should return a valid user"

  user.password_confirmation = nil

  # These are just some outputs to verify what's going on.
  # This is the condition in devises's password_required? method
  puts !user.persisted? || !user.password.nil? || !user.password_confirmation.nil? #=> true
  puts user.valid? #=> true

  assert user.invalid?, "Password confirmation should be required" # Fails here
  assert_equal 1, user.errors.size, "Only one error should have occured. #{user.errors.full_messages}"
end
```

This test fails at second assert (`"Password confirmation should be required"`).

Here's my full User model :

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_entity

  has_one :manager,through: :user_entity, source: :entity, source_type: 'Manager'
  has_one :client, through: :user_entity, source: :entity, source_type: 'Client'

  # Adds default behavior. See: https://github.com/stanislaw/simple_roles#many-strategy
  simple_roles

  validates :username,
    presence: true,
    length: { minimum: 4, allow_blank: true, if: :username_changed? },
    uniqueness: { allow_blank: true, if: :username_changed? },
    format: { with: /\A[A-z_0-9]+\z/, allow_blank: true, if: :username_changed? }

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :timeoutable, :omniauthable, :registerable
  devise  :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
          :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable

  # Virtual attribute for authenticating by either username or email
  # This is in addition to a real persisted field like 'username'
  attr_accessor :login

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup

    # User need to be active
    conditions[:active] = true

    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

  def entity
    self.user_entity.try(:entity)
  end

  def entity=(newEntity)
    self.build_user_entity(entity: newEntity)
  end

end
```

I've tried adding in my user model :

```
validates :password,    confirmation: true
```

After that the test passes but i get an error on the next one:

```
  1) Failure:
UserTest#test_user_requires_a_password [/my/project/test/models/user_test.rb:52]:
Two errors should have occured. ["Password confirmation doesn't match confirmation", "Password confirmation doesn't match confirmation", "Password can't be blank"].
Expected: 2
  Actual: 3
```

As you can see, it's like the confirmation validation occurs two times and fails both time.

I'm using rails4 (edge) and the rails4 branch for devise.

EDIT:
I tried setting

```
user.password_confirmation = "#{user.password}_diff"
```

And the test passes. So why is confirmation ignored when `nil` is set ? As the object is not yet persisted i would assume a password confirmation has to be provided.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question but I was having the same problem.

First, remove this from your model so you don't get duplicate validation checks:

```
validates :password, confirmation: true
```

Then add the following. I changed it to only work on create:

```
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create
```

See the **validates_confirmation_of** section on [this apidock page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html):

> NOTE: This check is performed only if password_confirmation is not nil. To require confirmation, make sure to add a presence check for the confirmation attribute:
>
> validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, if: :password_changed?